# ask for regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to write regex to detect `Double2` from this example:

`"(No1,No2,Double1)(No3,No4,Double2)(No5,No6,Double3)(No7,No8,Double4)"`

note:  I want to use variables in the first and the second numbers.

i.e.:

`int NB1 = something1`

`int NB2 = something2`

I try this but it does not work:
`"\\("+ NB1 +"\\,"+ NB2 +"\\,(\\d)*\\)"`

please, Any help?

Comment: Please explain the relevance of "something1" and in fact that whole section

Comment: "it does not work" is not very informative. What inputs did you try? What were the values of `something1` and `something2`? What result did you obtain and how was it different from what you want?

Comment: for example: `int NB1=3; int NB2=4;` 
`"(1,3,3.45)(3,4,5.55)(1,2,0.0)"`
it should return `5.55`

Comment: Try changing `\\,` to `,` in both places.

Comment: Figure out how to write the regex first, using an online tool such as http://regex101.com/.  Then figure out how to escape it to encode it in a Java String.

Comment: I still don't get the relevance of NB1 and NB2.

Comment: So Java auto-converts numbers<->strings (I don't know) ? There is a problem, the string you are searching does _NOT_ contain any numbers, nor will it ever. So that's the dilemma. For example "012" is a valid string, converted to int, then to string, it is "12". And there is always that decimal to int thing.

Comment: @Bohemian NB1 and NB2 are independent numbers

Comment: @sln java will do this conversion correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
"\\("+ NB1 +","+ NB2 +",([^)]*)\\)"
```

You need the quantifier (`*`) inside the capture group parentheses. Also, you want to match the decimal point, so you can't use `\\d`; you could use `[\\d,]` or what I suggest (everything up to the closing parentheses).